# R system2 run different scripts in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, system2

I believe using system2() is a good option for running two R scripts in parallel. I'm trying something like the following:

```
Sys.time()
system2(command = 'Sys.sleep(5)', wait = FALSE)
system2('Sys.sleep(7)', wait = FALSE)
Sys.time()
```

However, it does not work and I'm also getting this warning:

> running command '"Sys.sleep(7)"' had status 127

The documentation of system or system2 does not show any example and I can't find much around.
Has anyone tried this option to solve this problem?

Comment: Parameter `command` expects a system command, not an R command.

Comment: The R package **future** https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=future can be used to evaluate expressions in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
 system("Rscript -e 'Sys.sleep(5); \"task 1\"'", wait=FALSE)
 system("Rscript -e 'Sys.sleep(7); \"task 2\"'", wait=TRUE)
 [1] "task 1"
 [1] "task 2"
```

Version with `system2()` (thanks to the comment of HenrikB):

```
system2("Rscript", args = c("-e", "'Sys.sleep(5); \"task 1\"'"), wait=FALSE)
system2("Rscript", args = c("-e", "'Sys.sleep(7); \"task 2\"'"), wait=TRUE)
[1] "task 1"
[1] "task 2"
```

Comment: The first argument to `system2()` must be an executable, so you want to use `system2("Rscript", args = c("-e", "'Sys.sleep(5); \"task 1\"'"), ...)` in the latter case.